# Postmate create delivery pickup and dropoff params

Tags: postmates

I'm trying to create quotes/deliveries for a scheduled delivery using [Postmate API](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/#resources__delivery__create-delivery). The parameters given by PM is a bit confusing:

```
dropoff_ready_dt must be less than or equal to pickup_deadline_dt. This is to prevent a scenario where a courier has to hold onto an order between the pickup and dropoff windows.
```

For example: given now is 3PM, and expect the delivery to be dropped at the target side at 5PM.
What would be the good value for `pickup_ready_dt, pickup_deadline_dt, dropoff_ready_dt and dropoff_deadline_dt`?

Comment: I think the documentation and the error are both straight-forward and readable. What are you exactly stuck at?

Comment: Thanks @ram. Can you give some detail on why dropoff_ready_dt must be before pickup_deadline_dt? I imagine it would be like pickup_ready_dt > pickup_deadline_dt > .... delivery duration > dropoff_ready_dt > dropoff_deadline_dt. But it doesn't look that way from the explanation of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**`pickup_ready_dt`** must be less than 30 days in the future - *Let's say we give it as 3:01PM*

**`pickup_deadline_dt`** must be at least 10 mins later than `pickup_ready_dt` and at least 20 minutes in the future, thus providing a realistic pickup window - *3:21PM is the earliest that satisfies both conditions*

**`dropoff_ready_dt`** must be less than or equal to `pickup_deadline_dt`. This is to prevent a scenario where a courier has to hold onto an order between the pickup and dropoff windows - *Let's say 3:10PM*

**`dropoff_deadline_dt`** must be at least 20 mins later than `dropoff_ready_dt`, thus providing a realistic dropoff window. `dropoff_deadline_dt` must be greater than or equal to 'pickup_deadline_dt' - *The earliest time that we can provide is 3:30 PM*

> You've mentioned in your comment that `pickup_ready_dt > pickup_deadline_dt > .... delivery duration > dropoff_ready_dt > dropoff_deadline_dt`. But  according to the docs, the condition to be
> satisfied is `dropoff_ready_dt` <= `pickup_deadline_dt` and that's the corresponding error you see.

Comment: Thanks for explanation @ram. But I need the dropoff to be at 5PM, and with this parameters I really doubt that the returned `dropoff_eta` is not even close to what I'm expecting.

Comment: As I mentioned, its the **earliest** time possible. You can set the `dropoff_deadline_dt` to any time post 3:30PM, say 5PM

Comment: If you want the `dropoff_ready_dt` to be 5PM, then also set `pickup_deadline_dt` to 5PM, to abide by the condition `dropoff_ready_dt`  <= `pickup_deadline_dt`

Comment: I've tried this already and the returned dropoff_eta is pretty far away from expected 5PM for example 3:50PM.